# How to construct facebook open graph fitness metrics on android

Tags: java, android, facebook

Here is my code 
this function is creating fitness metrics.

```
protected ArrayList<ShareOpenGraphObject> 


setPathToPostToFacebook(ArrayList<Location> locations){

    ArrayList<ShareOpenGraphObject> metrics = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Location location : locations){
        ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder metric = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder();

        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:latitude", location.getLatitude());
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:longitude",location.getLongitude());
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:altitude",location.getAltitude());
        metric.putString("fitness:metrics:timestamp",new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
        metric.putInt("fitness:metrics:calories",5);
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:distance:value",50);
        metric.putString("fitness:metrics:distance:units","km");
        metric.putInt("fitness:metrics:steps",100);
        metric.putDouble("fitness:metrics:speed:value",50);
        metric.putString("fitness:metrics:speed:units","m");
        metrics.add(metric.build());//////
   }
   return metrics;
}
```

And this is the rest of the content.

```
ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
            .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
            .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
            .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
            .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
            .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
            .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
            .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
            .putObjectArrayList("fitness:metrics",metrics);



    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("fitness.runs")
            .putObject("fitness:course", object.build())
            .putString("fitness:start_time", FitnessModel.START_TIME)//.putPhoto("image",photo)
            .putString("fitness:end_time",new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString())
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
```

I have already asked this question twice on facebook's official developers page but there are too many question that they can answer at a time. I would really appreciate it if someone would answer this.